# UIPopoverPresentationController in swift

Tags: xcode, swift, controller, popover, presentation

I am making a small map type application. I wish to display a popover menu once the button 'morestuff' is clicked, but it does not seem to be appearing.

I have this code so far:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

var location: CLLocation!
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

// Map variables
var searchController:UISearchController!
var annotation:MKAnnotation!
var localSearchRequest:MKLocalSearchRequest!
var localSearch:MKLocalSearch!
var localSearchResponse:MKLocalSearchResponse!
var error:NSError!
var pointAnnotation:MKPointAnnotation!
var pinAnnotationView:MKPinAnnotationView!

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
@IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet weak var showSearchBar: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet weak var addButton: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet weak var moreStuff: UIBarButtonItem!


@IBAction func addButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

}

@IBAction func showSearchBar(sender: UIBarButtonItem!) {
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    presentViewController(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

@IBAction func refresh(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}



@IBAction func moreStuff(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showMoreStuff", sender:self)

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showMoreStuff"
    {
        var vc = segue.destinationViewController as! UIViewController

        var controller = vc.popoverPresentationController

        if controller != nil
        {
            controller?.delegate = self
        }

    }
}

func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {

    return .None
}


@IBAction func segmentedControl(sender: UISegmentedControl!) {

    if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0{

        mapView.mapType = MKMapType.Standard
    }
    else if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1{

        mapView.mapType = MKMapType.Satellite
    }
    else if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 2{

        mapView.mapType = MKMapType.Hybrid
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.locationManager.delegate = self

    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// location delegate methods

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let location = locations.last

    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)

    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))

    self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError)
{
    print("Error code: " + error.localizedDescription)
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar){

    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    if self.mapView.annotations.count != 0{
        annotation = self.mapView.annotations[0]
        self.mapView.removeAnnotation(annotation)
    }

    localSearchRequest = MKLocalSearchRequest()
    localSearchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery = searchBar.text
    localSearch = MKLocalSearch(request: localSearchRequest)
    localSearch.startWithCompletionHandler { (localSearchResponse, error) -> Void in

        if localSearchResponse == nil{
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "No Such Place", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return
        }

        self.pointAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        self.pointAnnotation.title = searchBar.text
        self.pointAnnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: localSearchResponse!.boundingRegion.center.latitude, longitude:     localSearchResponse!.boundingRegion.center.longitude)


        self.pinAnnotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: self.pointAnnotation, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        self.mapView.centerCoordinate = self.pointAnnotation.coordinate
        self.mapView.addAnnotation(self.pinAnnotationView.annotation!)
    }
}

}
```

Any help is appreciated :) I am trying to learn the Swift language myself

Comment: You would like to show view controller in UIPopover via segue ?

Comment: You don't need to use 'self.' in Swift, unless you're inside a closure. It would make your code look a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly your UIButton should be linked to the popover's view controller using the Present As Popover segue type.

Than add delegate method of the
**UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate** :

```
- (UIModalPresentationStyle)adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:(UIPresentationController *)controller {

    return UIModalPresentationNone;
}
```

Swift version :

```
func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(PC: UIPresentationController!) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    // This *forces* a popover to be displayed on the iPhone
    return .None
}
```

After that add **prepareForSegue:sender:** to you're code

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showMoreStuff"]) {
    UIViewController *dvc = segue.destinationViewController;
    UIPopoverPresentationController *controller = dvc.popoverPresentationController;
    if (controller) {
        controller.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does this code go specifically? I am new to Swift sorry :(

Comment: Specifically the first section of code, I am not sure where to put this

Comment: First section should be placed in viewController that is using UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have only 1 viewcontroller.swift file, when I place the code in there I get an unexpected declaration under the "-". Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Thanks, now the second block of code, I tried to replace my existing code with it but I receive errors about '@' etc. Is this swift?